# How to separate routes in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i created a simple app.js like this

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);


app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider

      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'html/home.html',

      });


});
```

but when i create a separate file routes.js

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'html/home.html',

});


});
```

The homepage is not shown. I double checked everything and i added the routes.js to the index page.

But it gives me this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined.
But i don't know why? the app is not an anonymous function.

This is my index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="routes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use `app` variable in `routes.js` you need to load this file after `app.js` where this variable is created:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="routes.js"></script>
```

Alternatively you could setup routes in separate modules and use those modules as dependencies to main module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'main', 'admin']);
```

and then for example in `main-moudle.js`:

```
angular.module('main', []).config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'html/home.html',
});
```

Comment: I knew i forgot something. i'm going to try putting them into a modules thanks for the advice.